# Understanding debug message related issues about trusted IPs and TLS handshake error in Traefik

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ssl, logging, reverse-proxy, traefik

I'm using [Kamal](https://kamal-deploy.org/) (old MRSK) with Rails and I'm able to run Traefik as a dynamic, transparent/TLS pass-through reverse proxy and load balancer.

By inspecting logs with `kamal traefik logs`, I see debug level messages like *"[IP 45.79.181.104 is not in trusted IPs list, ignoring ProxyProtocol Headers and bypass connection](https://github.com/traefik/traefik/blob/0ee377bc9f036124b063e7abc3f0958d51ace5fb/pkg/server/server_entrypoint_tcp.go#L421C65-L421C117)"* and *"http: TLS handshake error from 45.79.181.104:57510: read tcp 172.17.0.2:80->45.79.181.104:57510: read: connection reset by peer"*.

Should I take action to solve any related-issue about those debug messages or they are normal? My app seems to just work.

```
$ kamal traefik logs --lines=10
Traefik Host: 1x2.1y4.2z4.79
2023-12-26T17:47:08.689794554Z time="2023-12-26T17:47:08Z" level=debug msg="IP 45.79.181.104 is not in trusted IPs list, ignoring ProxyProtocol Headers and bypass connection" entryPointName=web
2023-12-26T17:47:08.767246219Z time="2023-12-26T17:47:08Z" level=debug msg="Serving default certificate for request: \"\""
2023-12-26T17:47:08.933166919Z time="2023-12-26T17:47:08Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 45.79.181.104:57510: read tcp 172.17.0.2:80->45.79.181.104:57510: read: connection reset by peer"
2023-12-26T17:55:50.692249811Z time="2023-12-26T17:55:50Z" level=debug msg="IP 45.93.20.119 is not in trusted IPs list, ignoring ProxyProtocol Headers and bypass connection" entryPointName=websecure
2023-12-26T17:55:52.694586478Z time="2023-12-26T17:55:52Z" level=debug msg="http: TLS handshake error from 45.93.20.119:63128: tls: client offered only unsupported versions: [302 301]"
2023-12-26T17:56:33.546454850Z time="2023-12-26T17:56:33Z" level=debug msg="IP 172.104.210.105 is not in trusted IPs list, ignoring ProxyProtocol Headers and bypass connection" entryPointName=web
2023-12-26T17:56:44.470419135Z time="2023-12-26T17:56:44Z" level=debug msg="IP 172.104.210.105 is not in trusted IPs list, ignoring ProxyProtocol Headers and bypass connection" entryPointName=web
2023-12-26T17:57:24.278542849Z time="2023-12-26T17:57:24Z" level=debug msg="IP 192.155.90.118 is not in trusted IPs list, ignoring ProxyProtocol Headers and bypass connection" entryPointName=web
2023-12-26T18:00:27.644899606Z time="2023-12-26T18:00:27Z" level=debug msg="IP 198.74.56.46 is not in trusted IPs list, ignoring ProxyProtocol Headers and bypass connection" entryPointName=web
2023-12-26T18:00:35.290311792Z time="2023-12-26T18:00:35Z" level=debug msg="IP 198.74.56.46 is not in trusted IPs list, ignoring ProxyProtocol Headers and bypass connection" entryPointName=web
```